# Software delay using C

Tags: c

This code just calculates the software delay but whenever I try running the code it throws the following errors.Thanks in advance
error: called object is not a function or function pointer
error:expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #define delay 12800
 
struct my_time
{
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;
};
void display(struct my_time *t);
void delay(void);
void update(struct my_time *t);
    
int main()
{
    struct my_time systime;
    systime.hours=0;
    systime.minutes=0;
    systime.seconds=0;
    
    while (1)
    {
        update(&systime);
        display(&systime);
    }

    return 0;
}
    
void update(struct my_time *t){
    t->seconds++;
    if(t->seconds==60){
        t->seconds=0;
        t->minutes++;
    }
    if(t-> minutes==60){
        t->minutes=0;
        t->hours++;
    }
    if(t->hours==24) t->hours=0;
    
    delay();
}
    
void display(struct my_time *t){
    
    printf("%02d: ", t->hours);
    printf("%02d:",t->minutes);
    printf("%02d\n",t->seconds);
}
    
void delay(void){
    long int t;
    for(t=0;t<delay;t++);
}
```

Comment: And what lines are the errors on?

Comment: `#define delay 12800`  but you also define a function `void delay(void);`, consider using `#define DELAY 12800`

Comment: In general, constants by `#DEFINE` are usually all written in CAPS.

Answer (score 1):

you have defined delay to be 12800. in the line below:

```
#define delay 12800
```

in preprocessor time, preprocessor pass on your code and replace each delay he finds with 12800. so you function call : `delay()`  becomes, `12800()`! this is invalid hence the error you have got.

defines are written in uppecase letters always!

e.g. use this:

```
#define DELAY_T 12800
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a `delay` [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion). This will replace ***every*** instance of `delay` in the program (except inside strings). `void delay(void);` becomes `void 12800(void);` and so on.

To avoid this, the convention is to use all caps for macros: `#define DELAY 12800`.

However, there's no need for a macro. Use a constant integer. `const int DELAY = 12800;` It effectively does the same thing, and it's safer.